# Remap RShift but allow it to work when it's combined with another key in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I have remapped the <kbd>RShift</kbd> in the following way:

```
~RShift::Send {LShift}
RShift UP::Send {Alt down}{LShift}{Alt up}
```

Here I have remapped  <kbd>RShift</kbd> to  <kbd>ALT+SHIFT</kbd>, but when I hold the  <kbd>RShift</kbd> and type something it will still perform as usual (will make it CAPS). My only problem is that when I release it still performs  <kbd>ALT+SHIFT</kbd> and I would want it not to, if I am holding it.

I have seen some explanation that it's somehow possible, but I simply can't find it. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, explanation in the comments:

```
RShift::
    Send, {LShift down}                     ; Send our Left Shift down
    KeyWait, RShift                         ; Wait until Right Shift is released
    If (A_TimeSinceThisHotkey < 500) {      ; If RShift was released very quickly do below..
        Send, {LSHift up}                   ; Release the initial Left Shift
        Send {Alt down}{LShift}{Alt up}     ; Send your sequence of keys
        Return                              ; exit from Sub Routine 
    }
    Else                                    ; else if Right Was held longer than 500 milliseconds
        Send, {LSHift up}                   ; Release the initial Left Shift
Return                                      ; exit from Sub Routine
```

Comment: Ahh.. you added a  KeyWait, now that is simply beautiul! Big kuddos :)